# TableView Disappears from the View Hierarchy Debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I use xCode 11.5. If I wrap an Empty UIView and a UITableView into a stack view and the choose Fill for the distribution way, the UITableView will disappear in the Simulator interface. I've checked the View Hierarchy Debugger and the UITableView is completely gone! If I switch the orders of the UIView and UITableview, then the UIView will be gone. Really weird problem and I tried searching the whole Internet for the reason with no luck. Can someone please help pointing out why this happened?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting the height of anyone, either UITableview or UIView inside UIStackView. you would get this if you would click on the red mark with a white arrow on view controller scene.